# How to show the values with explode if one value it´s array

Tags: php, post, explode

I have question about explode, because i have string with differents values separated by ",", and some values take from $_POST Array, for example multiselect fields, but i don´t know if i writte right this in PHP

**Take Values- in this case $_POST['opt']['selection'] it´s array :**

```
$values="house,car,colors,".$_POST['opt']['selection']."";
```

**As you can see in the other point in the string "$values", the different values are separated by "," and now i go to explode these values**

```
$exp_values=explode(",",$values);
```

**Now i try show all values :**

```
foreach($exp_values as $exp_values_end)
{

if(is_array($exp_values_end))
{

/// In this point must show values from array for process, and aplicate other time foreach, but don´t show nothing

}
else
{
$exp_values_end
}

}
```

I try different ways for get values from arrays when use with explode, but finally get nothing, by this, my questin it´s about, if it´s possible do this and how i can use explode when some values really are arrays, how in the case i show in this post, thank´s in advanced

**Thank´s**

Comment: `$values="house,car,colors,".$_POST['opt']['selection']."";` – that won’t work to begin with, you can not concatenate an array into a string like that, this will only get you the _word_ “Array” in that position. You would need to use _implode_ here first, to convert the array into a comma-separated string of values, that you could append to the rest. Or you start by just exploding the static values into an array first, and then _merge_ the two arrays.

Comment: And how i can do this i need please

Answer (score 0):

First you need to transform your string into array. You can create a function `convertStrToArray()` who's retuning arguments as array. With `...$listString` notation, you can add all your string variables.
I havn't tested it but you can try and debug :)

```php
function convertStrToArray(...$listString)
{
    return func_get_args();
}

$list = convertStrToArray('house', 'car', 'colors', $_POST['opt']['selection']);
```

Comment: The problem it´s i have one only string with different data, and som e data are arrays and i want explode this string with normal data and arrays and detect arrays in explode and can show also the information from these arrays, this it´s te question for me